# Problem with Arcam rpac and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound

I have recently (mistakenly?) purchased an Arcam rpac USB DAC for my Ubuntu (12.04) PC. I have torn out all but 3 of my hairs trying to get this to work and have had absolutely no luck so far.

I can see the Arcam USB audio device when i run aplay -l, however I cannot see it listed under the Sound settings. I can see the soundcard device when running alsamixer also, but if I try and select it, alsamixer crashes, stating "cannot load mixer controls: Invalid argument".

Any ideas how to get this working (if it's even possible)? Does anyone else out there have the rpac with Ubuntu?

Comment: ARCAM rPac on linux See the solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139547/arcam-rpac-usb-sound-card-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-04  

No pulseaudio uninstall needed.

Answer (score 0):

here there is a solution.. 
[ARCAM rPAC USB sound card not working on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139547/arcam-rpac-usb-sound-card-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-04)
but you have to uninstall `pulseaudio`. I tried it with Quantal and it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing an answer. I removed the second part of it since it would be more appropriate to ask that as a new questions, which you are more than welcome to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - turns out that even though I can identify my DAC in pulseaudio it won't work as long as pulseaudio is present. My DAC works now that I have removed pulseaudio but I have also lost my volume control. I can alter the PCM level in alsamixer to adjust volume but that seems rather cumbersome - any ideas how to set up alternate volume control?