# Is FiiO E10K DAC supported on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: sound, usb, external-soundcard

I am planning to get headphone DAC/AMP Fiio E10K. It has PCM 5102 chip. Its not same product as Fiio E10 – because the chip is different. I am wondering will it work with Ubuntu 14.04. If it does how will I get it do work. I am using Dell Latitude E5420. 
Information I have gathered this far:

Someone on Twitter claims it works great with Ubuntu Studio: 
https://twitter.com/maxisliwa/status/524537158099812352

Something I have heard on many reviews: This is a USB Audio Class 1 device that does not require drivers be installed, even on Linux.

Arcam rPAC with same DAC problem here: [ARCAM rPAC USB sound card not working on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139547/arcam-rpac-usb-sound-card-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-04)   Claims not to be working.

I really do not want to end up buying and then dissapointed.

About E10
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=15024

So does anyone has any information whether it works, is supported, or are there any workarounds? I send an e-mail to Fiio – also waiting their reply.

Received a short reply from FiiO Custom Service: "The E10K can be supported on Ubuntu. Kindly be noted that, the DAC chip(such as PCM5102) has nothing to do with the supportability on the computer OS, and it depends on the receiving chip in the circuit."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The E10K works well in Ubuntu 14.04.

To have the device recognized I have to reboot with the device plugged in.  I haven't yet figured out how to get the E10K recognized and installed as an sound output option without a reboot.

Comment: Aha! The following commands (don't type the quotation marks) allowed me to get the E10K running without a reboot: "sudo alsa reload" followed by "killall pulseaudio".  Then when I plugged in the E10K it appeared on the list of sound devices.

Comment: Hmm... But what type of output do you get for the device: Analog or Digital? It seems that many have trouble getting Digital output from FiiO products, as in [How do I enable digital output on a Fiio E7 without ending session](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334626/how-do-i-enable-digital-output-on-a-fiio-e7-without-ending-session). I tried  `sudo alsa reload` followed by `sudo killall pulseaudio`, and then plugged the FiiO X3 (with USB DAC enabled), but I'm still only seeing `DAC Analog Stereo`, and no digital port...

Answer (score 2):

User on reddit report affermative:

> have the new E10k running on Linux perfectly without any need to configure/install anything...

http://www.reddit.com/r/headphones/comments/2jcfdo/will_fiio_e10_work_with_a_linux_os/claevjl

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 14.04: E10K recognized without any problems. Two Devices in the sound settings: Analog USB and Digital USB (S/PDIF).

Comment: How is audio routed when you select Digital USB (S/PDIF) ? Does it go through the E10K's DAC and then to line-out / headphones jack? Or is it just routed to coaxial out?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Then reinsert the card, if it doesn't auto-mount try

```
sudo mount.exfat /dev/mmcblk0p1 /your/mount/point
```

Goodluck!

Comment: What?!? This answer makes no sense and has nothing to do with connecting a USB audio device. You do _not_ need to mount an exfat system in order to connect an USB audio device.